# entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe suddenly has high CPU load according to "perf record"

Tags: linux, performance, ubuntu, system-calls, perf

Its about a system call wasting a lot of CPU power in *several* situations. The problem, that I am facing, is shown by perf in using 20-35% CPU power for something I do not know.

I could find some (*older*) discussions and even bug reports concerning some kernel issue in various (!!!) linux distributions and version, but could not see any real solution.

(snapshot from `perf report --tui --sort symbol`)

```
-   20.93%     0.00%  [k] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe
   - entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe
      - 20.68% do_syscall_64
         - 12.13% __x64_sys_sched_yield
            - 12.03% do_sched_yield
               - 9.46% schedule
                  - 9.31% __schedule
                       8.23% finish_task_switch
                       0.87% arch_local_irq_enable
           5.13% syscall_enter_from_user_mode
         + 0.87% __x64_sys_mmap
         + 0.78% __x64_sys_madvise
```

Somebody even wrote a post (concerning Ubuntu 20.04), that the performance bug apears to have been magically solved on its own about 1 year ago.

As I do not do an hourly performance test, I can only guess, that this could have started arround the last system update switching to kernel **linux-tools-5.15.0-69-generic**.

Maybe I did not search for the correct things, as I do not really understand, what this is about, So I ask here, if somebody has some information or explanation for me, that helps me sort this out.

The situation in my case, is an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS guest running in VMPlayer 17 (newest) on Windows 10 Home running some self written engine using ZMQ and MYSQL. No significant load is used up by these frameworks, main load is some memory and CPU intensive own calculation, that used to work without that SYSCALL showing up. ... and suddenly this SYSCALL drains 1/3 CPU, indeed pushing the system to its limits.

What I tried is following:

- suspend and resume the VM Player
- restart the guest OS
- shutdown guest OS, restart VMPlayer and boot guest OS
- shutdown guest OS, restart host (win10) and reboot VM Player & guest OS
- shutdown guest OS, shutdown host (win10), boot host and boot VM Player & guest OS

None of these actions changed anything concerning the CPU load by that syscall.

Comment: What CPU are you running on?

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz   1.99 GHz
... in the Yoga 920, but the issue shows in the VM Player (V17)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting that correctly, I think you have a user-space process making lots of `sched_yield(2)` system calls, perhaps while spin-waiting for something?

Profiling / tracing user-space system calls should identify which process is making `sched_yield()` calls.  Perhaps with `strace -f -e sched_yield -p <PID>` on some of your active processes to see if they're the offender.

---

All system calls go through the `syscall` entry point in `entry_64.S`, and the spectre/meltdown protections add a lot of overhead before getting to the code that does the actual system call.

Microcode updates to [IBRS support](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/hw-vuln/spectre.html), as well as kernel changes to default mitigation strategies can affect how expensive this is, as well as new vulnerabilities being discovered that add new more expensive mitigations, like retbleed.  (https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/hw-vuln/index.html).

Newer CPUs sometimes have more efficient HW support for mitigating Spectre, and may have hardware fixes for other things and not require mitigations.  Newer software on older hardware may be slower, adding more overhead to mitigate more known vulnerabilities.

Comment: thanks for this explanation (Y). Sounds for me as if >I< dont really see much chances in solving this in a determined way (far too few knowledge upon this on my side).
What I wonder about is, that it used to work smoothly until a couple of days ago and everything (!) was cleanly rebooted but the issue persists. As for "whats going on in the process", its mainly some dozen ZMQ sockets (PUB, SUB, XREQ and XREP) polling, but I would expect that polling to be properly handled insidde ZMQ lib as I never saw this before for years of working on this.